# How to get the physical path of a file?

Tags: php, file, path

my client has migrated his server, the server address is the same, but the internal folders structure has changed, I was working with a PHP function that needed the server path to a file

For example, the website address is www.example.com/file.php and my function is using the path like this:

```
require_once('/var/www/file.php');
```

Is there a way to find out?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since this is the first hit on Google and the accepted answer is incomplete according to the spirit of the question, here is the complete answer.

---

`__FILE__` is a *magical constant* like John Conde said, but it only gives you the physical path for the current PHP file that is being executed.

`__DIR__` gets you the directory of the currently executed file. Alternately, you can also use `dirname(__FILE__)`

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` gets the physical path to the web root, e.g. `/var/www/example.com/httpdocs`

For instance, lets say your website has the following folder structure:

```
|-foo
|  |-bar
|     |-executing.php
|-biz
   |-required.php
```

Lets say `executing.php` is the file the is currently being executed and you want to include `required.php`. You have a few options.

```
//relative to the file
require __DIR__ . "/../../biz/required.php";
require dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../biz/required.php";

//relative to the web root
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/biz/required.php";
```

Of course, in any of these example, you can also use `require_once` instead of `require`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [magic constant `__FILE__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: More detailed: It must be something like `dirname(__FILE__) . '/relative/path/to/file.php'`, or (for PHP5.3+) `__DIR__ . '/relative/path/to/file.php'`

Comment: I should print the result of dirname(__FILE__) . '/relative/path/to/file.php' or just leave it there?

Comment: If you only want the directory use `__DIR__`. If you want the full path with the file name use `__FILE__`.

Comment: `__FILE__` or `__DIR__` gets you the location of the php file you are running. Not of `/var/www/file.php`. This will `require(__DIR__.'file.php')` will only work if it is in the same directory of the file that is requiring the file. `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` should give you the root directory of the website.